# LINQ sum with grouping, but also get line item value before grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of type Cars like below `List<Car> cars`:

| ID | Colour | Make | Model | Km |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | BMW | M3 | 1000 |
| 2 | Red | BMW | 318i | 1000 |
| 3 | Black | Mercedes | C200 | 1000 |
| 4 | Black | Mercedes | E200 | 1000 |
| 5 | White | Mercedes | CLA200 | 1000 |
| 6 | White | Mercedes | E200 | 1000 |
| 7 | White | Mercedes | E200 | 2000 |
| 8 | White | Mercedes | E200 | 3000 |

Now what I want to do is, using LINQ (or maybe another way if not possible with LINQ) I want to group them by Colour, Make, Model and then add another column and assign to list of another type (`<CarDetail>`) which will give the weighted average of the line in the group by.

As an example, on last 3 Cars, the new column will show (Total Km for that group = 1000+2000+3000 = 6000).

```
6 => 1000/6000
7 => 2000/6000
8 => 3000/6000
```

What  I have tried so far is :

```
List<CarDetail> carDetails =
                cars.
                GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    x.Colour,
                    x.Make,
                    x.Model
                }).
            Select(h => new CarDetail
            {
                Colour= h.Key.Colour,
                Make= h.Key.Make,
                Model= h.Key.Model,                    
                WeightedKm = x.Km  / h.Sum(x => x.Km )
            }).ToList();
```

h.Sum(x => x.Km ) will bring the sum of Km.s but trying to use "x.Km" surely doesn't work.

Can anyone help on how to get this list please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grouping is conceptually a list of lists. It seems you want to unpack this to a simple list, using an aggregation of the sub list along the way. The process for turning a list of lists into a list is a SelectMany

```
var carDetails = cars
        .GroupBy(c => new
        {
            c.Colour,
            c.Make,
            c.Model
        })
        .SelectMany(g => g, (subList, aCarInTheSublist) => new CarDetail
        {
            Colour= aCarInTheSublist.Colour,
            Make= aCarInTheSublist.Make,
            Model= aCarInTheSublist.Model,                    
            WeightedKm = (double)aCarInTheSublist.Km  / subList.Sum(aCar => aCar.Km ) //cast to double because int math 1000/3000 = 0
        }).ToList();
```

Attacking it with a Select will run into trouble because what you're selecting is the group i.e. the outer list. Taking this simpler example:

```
A, 1
A, 2
A, 3
B, 1
```

If you group by the letter, your output only has 2 rows:

```
A -> {A,1} {A,2} {A,3}
B -> {B,1}
```

so you'll struggle to get back to the 4 rows you want, because the Select is only run twice.

SelectMany will visit each entry in the group (i.e. the two groups A and B, the A group having 3 sub-entries) and visit each one of the sub entries, so for the A group (a single group with 3 members, A1, A2 and A3) it will result in projecting 3 elements out. Crucially because, whilst it visits each of A1, A2 and A3, access to the group A as a whole is still available so you can sum it all the KMs in it

It's perhaps not very efficient, because we're summing up the group repeatedly but LINQ doesn't always win efficiency contests :)

You could consider trading CPU time in summing for memory in remembering the sum by putting the sums in a dictionary:

```
    var d = cars
        .GroupBy(c => new
        {
            c.Colour,
            c.Make,
            c.Model
        })
        .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Sum(c=>c.Km));

    var result = cars
        .Select(c => new CarDetail
        {
            Colour= c.Colour,
            Make= c.Make,
            Model= c.Model,                    
            WeightedKm = (double)c.Km  / d[new{c.Colour,c.Make,c.Model}]
        }).ToList();
```

Side note, when using LINQ try and keep aliases representative of what the list entry is. `cars` is a list of car, so `Select(c =>` to help keep straight that it's a car.

A `GroupBy(c=>...).Select(g=>` reminds you that you're grouping up cars and then Select is operating on a grouping. Each item within the grouping is a Car, so you might like `Select(gc=>` for "group of cars", and `Select(gc=> gc.Select(c=>` the second select is operating on an enumerable of Car, so reverting to `c` helps clarify that

Comment: Thanks, I tried the Linq solution and it worked as expected, haven't tried the dictionary alternative yet. And in the Linq method so many aliases, for example, that `.SelectMany(g => g,` I will try to name them to be more meaningful for me as you have suggested.